# Can the producer/consumer ( bounded-buffer ) be sped up through openMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm implementing the producer/consumer problem for homework, and I have to compare the sequential algorithm with the parallel one, and my parallel one seems to only be able to run either at the same speed or slower than the sequential one. I've come to the conclusion that using a queue is a limiting factor and it won't speed up my algorithm.

Is this the case or am I just coding it wrong?

```
int main() {
    long sum = 0;
    unsigned long serial = ::GetTickCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < test; i++){
        enqueue(rand()%54354);
        sum+= dequeue(); 
    }
    printf("%d \n",sum);

    serial = (::GetTickCount() - serial);
    printf("Serial Program took: %f seconds\n", serial * .001);
    sum = 0;
    unsigned long omp = ::GetTickCount();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(128) default(shared) 
    for(int i = 0; i < test; i++){
        enqueue(rand()%54354);
        sum+= dequeue(); 

    }

    #pragma omp barrier //joins all threads
    omp = (::GetTickCount() - omp);
    printf("%d \n",sum);
    printf("OpenMP Program took: %f seconds\n", omp * .001);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I see `num_threads(128)`. Do you really have 128 cores/threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

You have `rand()` inside the parallel region.

**`rand()` is not thread-safe.** It uses global/static variables. So calling it concurrently from multiple threads will lead to unexpected (possibly undefined) behavior.

That aside, the data-races resulting from concurrent calls to `rand()` will lead to a lot of cache coherency stalls. This is likely the source of the slowdown.

---

**Problem #2:**

**Is `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` thread-safe?**

If it isn't, then you need to fix that first. If it is, how are you synchronizing it?

If it's just a critical region that allows only one thread at a time to access the queue, then that kind of defeats the whole purpose of parallelism.

---

**Problem #3:**

This line modifies the `sum` variable in each iteration:

```
sum += dequeue();
```

Note that all the threads will be doing this concurrently. So you need to declare `sum` as a reduction variable.

Comment: I will try to prebuffer some values instead of using rand then.

What would constitute a thread safe function though?

Here's my enqueue:

`void enqueue(int n) {
 if(isFull != 0) {
 que.arr[que.next] = n;
 que.next += 1;
 que.next = que.next%MAX;
 que.size++;
 }
}`

Comment: Overall, the task you have here is not a good candidate for parallelism. So even if you manage to fix all these problems, I highly doubt you'll gain any speedup unless you do some very messy transformations.

Comment: As you can see, I'm overall lost in how to do this correctly, so I'll take as much help as I can get.

Comment: Making it thread-safe isn't going to make it faster. So it's probably the wrong question to ask. A "queue" (almost by definition) is inherently sequential. So it can't be parallelized. You can make your code thread-safe by putting locks or critical sections around every operation that isn't thread-safe. But that won't make it faster because that will sequentialize such operations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10955/discussion-between-jesus-adobo-luzon-and-mysticial)